# Characterisation of representation-directed algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

A representation-directed algebra $A$ over a field $K$ has the property that for every indecomposable module $M$ we have $\mathrm{End}_A(M) \cong K$ and $\mathrm{Ext}_A^i(M,M)=0$ for all $i>0$.

> Question: In case for every indecomposable module $M$ we have $\mathrm{End}_A(M) \cong K$ and $\mathrm{Ext}_A^i(M,M)=0$ for all $i>0$, is $A$ representation-directed?
>   Is it true under the additional assumption that $A$ is representation-finite?